# Grid in Canvas, last cells' sizes are not the same as the others

Tags: java, canvas, grid

How Do I paint the canvas with the grids having equal sizes?
problem: http://tinypic.com/r/idvc0j/5 
the code draws the last cells with sizes not parallel to the other cells.
what change do i have to do in the paint() method?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Grid extends Canvas{

    Cell[][] maze;
    int rows;
    int cols;

    Grid(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        maze = new Cell[rows][cols];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Sample");
        Grid x = new Grid(25,25);
        f.add(x);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int k;
    int width = getSize().width;
    int height = getSize().height;

    int htOfRow = height / (rows);
    for (k = 0; k < rows; k++)
        g.drawLine(0, k * htOfRow , width, k * htOfRow );

    int wdOfRow = width / (cols);
    for (k = 0; k < cols; k++)
        g.drawLine(k*wdOfRow , 0, k*wdOfRow , height);
    }
}

class Cell {

//  private final static int NORTH = 0;
//  private final static int EAST = 1;
//  private final static int WEST = 2;
//  private final static int SOUTH = 3;
//  private final static int NO = 0;
//  private final static int START = 1;
//  private final static int END = 2;
//  boolean[] wall = new boolean[4];
//  boolean[] border = new boolean[4];
//  boolean[] backtrack = new boolean[4];
//  boolean[] solution = new boolean[4];
//  private boolean isVisited = false;
//  private boolean isCurrent = false;
//  private int Key = 0;
//  
//  public Cell(){
//  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){wall[i] = true;}
//  }
//  public void setStart(int i){Key = i;}   
//  public int getKey(){return Key;}
//  public boolean checkVisit(){return isVisited;}
//  public void stepIn(){
//      isCurrent = true;
//      isVisited = true;
//  }
//  public void stepOut(){isCurrent = false;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rounding too early. `htOfRow` and `wdOfRow` are not exact `int` values. By casting them to `int` you let small errors accumulate over the span of the whole grid.

Instead, keep them as `double`, multiply them by `k` and only then cast them back to `int`.

For example:

If `width = 100` and `cols = 8` then `wdOfRow = 12.5`.

If you cast it to an `int` before multiplying by `k` when `k=8` then you place your last line at `12*8=96`.

If you multiply as `double` then cast to `int`, your last line will be at `12.5*8 = 100`

Here's the fixed code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Layout
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame( "Sample" );
        Grid x = new Grid( 50, 50 );
        f.add( x );
        f.pack( );
        f.setVisible( true );
        f.setSize( 600, 600 );
        f.setResizable( false );
        f.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }

    static class Cell
    {

    }

    public static class Grid extends Canvas
    {

        Cell[][] maze;
        int rows;
        int cols;

        Grid( int rows, int cols )
        {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.cols = cols;
            maze = new Cell[rows][cols];
        }

        public void paint( Graphics g )
        {
            int k;

            double width = getSize( ).width;
            double height = getSize( ).height;

            double htOfRow = height / ( rows );
            for ( k = 0; k < rows; k++ )
                g.drawLine( 0, ( int ) ( k * htOfRow ), ( int ) width, ( int ) ( k * htOfRow ) );

            double wdOfRow = width / ( cols );
            for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++ )
                g.drawLine( ( int ) ( k * wdOfRow ), 0, ( int ) ( k * wdOfRow ), ( int ) height );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, ignore my previous comment which I edited, this works. I did not think that the rounding off is affecting the program. Another solution I thought is to make the size of the JFrame that loads Canvas be 606 x 628 where the borders at the side are 3 px each and 28 px for the top and bottom.

Comment: Ok, I posted my whole fixed test code. If you just copy and run that verbatim, what do you see?

Comment: is the line
Rectangle rect = this.getBounds( );
really needed? it seems that you did not use it and when I compiled, it gets the same result.

Comment: No you're right. It's not necessary. I've edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: Another way to do it is to recognize that you can't get even division for arbitrary sizes; get the remainder from your integer division and add one to the quotient that many times, then use the quotient for the rest of that dimension.  That makes the divisions as even as they're going to get, and doesn't involve a bunch of casting.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more line in each direction.  if you do k <= rows and k <= cols, it divides things up as I think you want it.